# Can the primary group ID assigned to the user be the same as the user ID?

Tags: linux, unix

I've noticed something odd in my file permissions schema. The user id is 500 but the primary group set to the user is also 500 (same as user ID). Is this allowed? I am running into permission problems on my apache server and am wondering if this is related. I don't see a group that exists with a user id of "500" in etc/groups. When i run 'cat etc/passwd', the user with the id of 500 has 500 for the group as well .. but that group doesn't exist. But if it didn't exist, wouldn't an error be thrown when it was originally created?

The specific server errors I am encountering (in apache) are definitely unix permission related:

> [Fri Nov 01 11:25:44 2013] [error] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/sagedev/directory_name/index.php" is writeable by group

Comment: The missing entry in `/etc/group` is a problem, but it doesn't mean the group doesn't exist; it merely doesn't have a name. Check the permissions on the file referred to in the error message; apparently it shouldn't be group-writeable.

Comment: @KeithThompson that's what's odd, the file is in fact NOT group writable, chmoded to 644. I've tried all sorts of other permission schemes including 777 - no luck.

Answer (score 4):

uid and gid are separate namespaces. It's perfectly reasonable to have a user 500 who belongs to group 500, or a user 500 that belongs to group 501 while user 501 belongs to group 500, or a user 500 and a group 500 that have nothing to do with each other.

Files with nonexistent group ownership are not good though, and users with a nonexistent gid in the passwd file are definitely not good. You need to find out how they got that way. Did you delete the group that used to have gid 500?

Run these commands:

```
pwck
grpck
```

to check for other inconsistencies in your passwd file, and this one:

```
find /home \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print
```

to search for files with nonexistent owners/groups.

Comment: after doing a little research I discovered that lunix by default assigns a group which "has the same name as the user and with the gid equal to the uid." But if this is true, shouldn't the group with the same uid show up in etc/group? I'll try running your commands but i don't have root login. Anything i can do without root login?

Comment: @ChrisScott That method (every user gets a separate group with identical name and id) is a common convention among popular Linux distributions. It hasn't always been that way, and it's not a hard requirement. But yes, if you were using that convention, it would show up in `/etc/group`

Comment: i'm an idiot, 500 is in fact listed in /etc/group only I didn't scroll down. So I guess group and user permissions are set correctly and accounted for .. doesn't help solve my server error though. i'd upvote you if i had the ability (new user)

Comment: @ChrisScott all right then, for the main question, you should probably reorganize it and tag it for php since it looks like php is disapproving of the everything-is-group-writable-because-every-user-is-in-a-separate-group setup.